# Given 2 points and a radius, find the equation of the circle

Tags: analytic-geometry

Find the general equation of the circle with radius 5 and contains the points $A=(-8,0)$ and $B=(-4,-2)$.

Comment: I don't know where to start

Comment: I don't know if this will help but my professor put a hint, "Hint: Equate radii. Or use the fact that D = h^2+k^2-r^2, then, systems."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\Omega $ be the desired circle.
The equation of this circle is
$\Omega  : (x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 = 5^2$
Where $I (a,b)$ is the center of $\Omega $
$$A \in \Omega\quad \text {and}\quad B \in \Omega\\
\begin {align}
&\Leftrightarrow
\begin {cases}
(-8 - a)^2 + b^2 = 5^2\\
(-4 - a)^2 + (-2-b)^2 = 5^2
\end{cases} \\
&\Leftrightarrow
\begin {cases}
a^2 + 16a + 64 + b^2 - a^2 -  8a - 16 -  b^2 - 4b - 4 = 0\\
a^2 + 8a + 16 + b^2 +4b +4 = 5^2
\end{cases} \\
&\Leftrightarrow
\begin {cases}
8a - 4b + 44 = 0\\
a^2 + 8a  + b^2 +4b  -5 =0
\end{cases} \\
&\Leftrightarrow
\begin {cases}
2a - b + 11 = 0\\
a^2 + 8a  + b^2 +4b  -5 =0
\end{cases} \\
&\Leftrightarrow
\begin {cases}
b  = 2a + 11\\
a^2 + 8a  + (2a+ 11)^2 + (44 +8a)  -5 =0
\end{cases} \\
&\Leftrightarrow
\begin {cases}
b  = 2a + 11\\
a^2 + 8a  + 4a^2+ 44a + 121 +8a + 39 =0
\end{cases} \\
&\Leftrightarrow
\begin {cases}
b  = 2a + 11\\
 5a^2+ 60a + 160  =0
\end{cases}\\
&\Leftrightarrow
\begin {cases}
b  = 2a + 11\\
 a^2+ 12a + 32  =0 \quad \Delta = 144 - 128 =16
\end{cases}\\
&\Leftrightarrow
\begin {cases}
b  = 2a + 11\\
a_1= \frac {-12+4}2 \quad a_1= \frac {-12- 4}2 
\end{cases}\\
&\Leftrightarrow
\begin {cases}
b  = 2a + 11\\
a_1= -4 \quad a_2= -8
\end{cases}\end {align}\\
\Leftrightarrow  (a_1,b_1) = (-4,3)\quad\text {or}\quad(a_2,8) = (-8,-5)$$
So there exists exaclty two circles:

The first $\Omega_1$ with center $(-4,3)$.

And the second $\Omega_2$ with center $(-8,-5)$.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a unique circle satisfying these properties. (To visualize this, plot any two points, and draw the two circles of equal radii that go through those two points.)

Comment: True, but there are only two circles.

Comment: I don't know if this will help but my professor put a hint, "Hint: Equate radii. Or use the fact that D = h^2+k^2-r^2, then, systems."

Comment: Ross: Yes, but the question was to find *the* equation of *the* circle.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  if the center is $(x,y)$, the statement that $(-8,0)$ is at a distance $5$ from it means $(x-(-8))^2+(y-0)^2=5^2$.   You can get a second equation from the other point.  Solve them simultaneously.  You should find two points $(x,y)$ that satisfy the equations.  Write the equation for a radius $5$ circle around each one.

Comment: I don't get it, why would it be possible to put (-8,0) to the place of (h,k) if it isn't the points of the center of the circle?

Comment: You want the center to be $5$ units from $(-8,0)$, so we draw a circle of radius $5$ around $(-8,0)$ and say the center must be somewhere on the circle.

Comment: Oh i get what your saying now, but still i'm confused  on how to solve this question.

Comment: Can you write the corresponding equation based on $(-4,-2)$?  That gives you two equations in two unknowns.  As you have a quadratic, there are two solutions.  They correspond to the two different circles that each pass through the given points.

Comment: (x+4)^2 + (y+2)^2 = 5^2

Comment: That is right.  Now solve the two equations for $x,y$  You can subtract them to remove the squared terms from one, solve that for one of the variables, substitute into the other, and have a one variable quadratic.